# Decorator to map view functions to endpoint separate from defining url rule

Tags: python, flask, decorator

I want to build a view_functions dictionary by call my decorate!

```
view_functions = {}

def route(rule):
    def _route(function_name):
        def __route(function_arg):
            view_functions[rule] = function_name
        return __route
    return _route

if __name__ == '__main__':
    @route('hey')
    def hello(arg):
        print 'hello ',arg

    #hello('ap') if you have no call the function directly,you will got view_function have no key 'hey' ...That's my question! 
    view_functions['hey']('pp')
```

How can I just simple put the decorate above view_function (just like Flask) and then my view_functions dictionary will fill itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dict assignment is at the wrong level. It needs to be at the *outer* one, which is called at definition time. In this instance, the inner function doesn't actually need to do anything (apart from calling the decorated function, of course).

```
view_functions = {}
def route(rule):
    def _route(function_name):
        view_functions[rule] = function_name
        def __route(function_arg):
            function_name(function_arg)
        return __route
    return _route
```

Also note your definition of `hello` shouldn't be inside the `if __name__` block.